# How do I check if my mysql database causes slow down

Tags: mysql, database, performance, cpu-usage

I have around 3 websites residing in a server which is being shared with other teams. I have been notified that there is a huge increase in CPU usage and we need to lower it down. I doubt my websites are causing this.

I have been using SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST in MySQL and 90% of the time shows queries from other databases. But I think executing multiple SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST commands is not enough proof. How can I verify that my databases aren't CPU hogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you suspect that its a MySQL query, try inspecting the [MySQL Slow Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/slow-query-log.html). The log will help you identify queries that take long time to execute. You can then copy-paste the query text into a MySQL query session, execute it and observe the CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to install different MySQL release, that allows to track exact user statistics and some other things:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/16/mysql-releases-with-percona-patches/